# Use OpenAPI to generate Java APIs that don't return ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I want to generate a Java API using OpenAPI 3.0, but I don't want any return type to be a ResponseEntity.

I have a small .yaml file that generates APIs that look like this (I've removed lots of annotations for brevity):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student", produces = { "application/json" })
ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getAllStudents();
```

It's very straightforward, but my employer wants an API like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student")
List<Student> getAllStudents();
```

The trouble is that I can't find a configuration option that would make the code generator dispense with the ResponseEntities.

Is there any way to configure the OpenAPI generator to not use ResponseEntities?

—

**Details:**

I build with Maven, and I configure my code generation in my pom file like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
      <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
      <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <!--See https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin-->
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/OpenApi.yaml</inputSpec>
            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
            <groupId>com.dummy.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
            <artifactVersion>2.0</artifactVersion>
            <library>spring-boot</library>
            <packageName>com.neptunedreams.configuration</packageName>
            <apiPackage>com.neptunedreams.api</apiPackage>
            <invokerPackage>com.neptunedreams</invokerPackage>
            <modelPackage>com.neptunedreams.model</modelPackage>
            <configOptions>
              <!--See https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md -->
              <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
              <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
              <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
              <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
            </configOptions>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

My yaml file is very basic, if you need to see it:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  description: StackOverflow ResponseEntity Question
  version: 1.0.0
  title: ResponseEntity Question
paths:
  /student:
    get:
      summary: Get all students
      operationId: getAllStudents
      responses:
        200:
          description: Get all students
          content: 
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Student'

components: 
  schemas: 
    Student:
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
      required:
        - name
        - id
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change return types for Spring openapi-generator-maven-plugin generated interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476389/change-return-types-for-spring-openapi-generator-maven-plugin-generated-interfac)

Answer (score 3):

As of version 6.5.0 of the plugin, there is a flag you can add when using Spring

`useResponseEntity` should be set to false to disable the ResponseEntity from being in return types.

For example, your config options may look like this:

```
<configOptions>
    <library>spring-boot</library>
    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
    <reactive>true</reactive>
    <useResponseEntity>false</useResponseEntity>
</configOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like here [How to prevent Mono Request body generation when generating the API interfaces for spring-webflux with open api code generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73614880/how-to-prevent-mono-request-body-generation-when-generating-the-api-interfaces-f)
You can override/customize the `api.mustache` from swagger-codegen template.

Here you can find the original template https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/api.mustache

So you can put your own template inside src/main/java/resource.

```
openApiGenerate {   
    generatorName = "spring"
    library = "spring-boot"
    ...
    configOptions = [
    ...
    templateDirectory: "src/main/resources/openapi-templates"
    ...
    ]
}
```

Here is the documentation about template https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md

Comment: My employer won't want to pay me to modify template files. I've looked at the mustache files, and it's clear that modifying them would be a time-consuming process with several test cycles. My employer wants these Spring-Boot RESTful servers built quickly. That's why I want to use OpenAPI.
It sounds like you're telling me that there's no way to do this with the current tool.

Comment: Didn't find anything else than that. Had the same problem yesterday. This is/was the only solution i found and that helps me.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for methods without a return type. "Void" is capitalized and because Mustache is logicless I cannot implement an if/else there to treat this special case. Seems I have to wait for the PR on https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/6135 to be merged.

Comment: You can see the openapi project reach 3.5k issues, and 419 orphans Merge Request .....  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues